# '96 Buick Century Turn Signal Not Working

Tags: electrical, turn-signal, buick

Yesterday I noticed that all four of my turn signals were not turning on. About two months I had the flasher replaced because they turned on but just would not blink, now they will not even light up... as dead as the dodo.

Thinking it was a similar issue, I had an electrical diagnostic done. I was told that the electrical harness was fried and needed to be replaced, costing about $600!

Seemed weird to me, since the hazard lights engage and flash all of the lights, but cars and I don't have the best relationships, so I really have no idea.

I was wondering if it could be the flasher again? Or potentially a switch in the steering column where the turn switch actually resides (two months ago I also had the problem of the left blinker not auto-disengaging, so my car just hates blinkers apparently... or me.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I brought the car to another mechanic to fix whatever was wrong. As they started looking into it they quickly identified the flasher was burnt out. They replaced it and everything is good to go. Much cheaper than $600!